# How to add a tag/value to a JSONObject in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'd like to send some JSON data to a server from a GWT client app.

I'm trying this:

```
JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
String v1 = "string"
int v2 = 1000
JSONArray v3 = new JSONArray();
v3.put(1);
v3.put(2);

parameters.put("key1", v1);
parameters.put("key2", v2);
parameters.put("key3", v3);
```

The issue is JSONObject.put() takes a JSONValue as a 2nd parameter and I can't see how I can create a JSONValue as it's an abstract class. How can I put the values of Ints, Strings and arrays into a JSONObject via put(). Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `JSONValue` subclass has a constructor (except `JSONBoolean` which has a static factory method `getInstance`).

```
v3.set(0, new JSONNumber(1));
v3.set(1, new JSONNumber(2));

parameters.put("key1", new JSONString(v1));
parameters.put("key2", new JSONNumber(v2));
parameters.put("key3", v3);
```

Comment: alas, GWT doesn't implement set() for JSONArray. Any other route to handling arrays?

Comment: Do you mean [`JSONArray#set`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONArray.html#set%28int,%20com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONValue%29) is buggy? or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I'm saying Google Web Toolkit doesn't implement JSONArray#set

Comment: Are we talking about the same `JSONArray`? GWT doesn't have `org.json`, it has its own `com.google.gwt.json` which is not meant to be compatible; and it does have `set()`: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONArray.java, with unit-tests: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/test/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONTest.java

Comment: my error! Eclipse was insisting on inserting org.json. Over-typing that import with com.google.get.json.client.JSONArray gave access to set(). thanks for your persistence.